# Set focus on img src

Tags: php, javascript, setfocus

I have something like a comment box and I have a delete button like this for every comment.

When i click on the `img` to delete my comment it works well, but focuses on the TOP of the page.

Can I somehow focus it on the comment that I am about to delete, or can I only focus on the top or bottom of the page? I'm not sure if this is confusing...

```
  <a href="#" onclick="deletedata('<?php echo $row['CommentID'];?>')" 
     style="color:#FF0000; float:right;margin-right:20px;">
            <img src="images/trash.png" style="background:#FFFFFF" />
  </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `return false` to the end of your Javascript statement to prevent the href from being followed:

```
onclick="deletedata('<?php echo $row['CommentID'];?>'); return false;"
```

Comment: Having `href="javascript:void(0)"` would also work, but this is nicer :)